# Use ID inserted with `INSERT OR IGNORE` in next `INSERT` statement

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, insert, prepared-statement

I use sqlite 3.7 and have a schema that looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS predicates (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    predicate TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS objects (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    object BLOB NULL UNIQUE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statements (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    subject INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES subjects(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
    predicate INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES predicates(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT, 
    object INTEGER NULL REFERENCES objects(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);
```

To insert a row into `statements` I first INSERT OR IGNORE the `predicate` and the `object`, then I retrieve the ids:

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO predicates(predicate) VALUES (?)
```

```sql
SELECT predicates.id FROM predicates WHERE predicates.predicate = ?
```

To finally execute

```sql
INSERT INTO statements(subject, predicate, object) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

I my question is: **Is there a way to directly do these (prepared) statements in one go?**

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO predicates(predicate) VALUES (?);
SELECT predicates.id FROM predicates WHERE predicates.predicate = ?;
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO objects(object) VALUES (?);
SELECT predicates.id FROM objects WHERE objects.object = ?;
INSERT INTO statements(subject, predicate, object) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[last_insert_rowid()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) works only if some row was actually inserted.

You always might need the SELECTs, but you can do them as subqueries:

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO predicates(predicate) VALUES (?);
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO objects(object) VALUES (?);
INSERT INTO statements(subject, predicate, object)
VALUES (?,
        (SELECT id FROM predicates WHERE predicate = ?),
        (SELECT id FROM objects WHERE object = ?)
       );
```

Comment: I did not know that I can use a subquery in an insert statement. Thank you, very nice! I'll try it tomorrow.